# Exchange Web Services SMTP address error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, office365, exchangewebservices

***Please see edit below before reading all this:***

---

### Problem

I'm trying to access my own calendar programmatically via Exchange Web Services on SharePoint 2010. It was working earlier today and as far as I know nothing has changed so this is very confusing. The error I'm getting is saying

> The SMTP address has no mailbox associated with it

Here is the general error, and the stack trace:
[image: General Error]

[image: Stack Trace]

---

### Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data" %>
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">  
    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Michael.Wiley@<SOME DOMAIN>", "<CORRECT PASSWORD>");
            service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            // Initialize values for the start and end times, and the number of appointments to retrieve.
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
            const int NUM_APPTS = 5;

            // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
            CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet());

            // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
            Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView cView = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

            // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
            cView.PropertySet = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);

            // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
            FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

            foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
            {
                Response.Write(a.Subject.ToString() + "<br />");
            }
    }
</script>
```

---

I looked for a couple ways to fix this, here are the suggestions I saw:

1. Email is incorrect or not primary SMTP address
2. Password is incorrect
3. If impersonating user must be set as delegate in permissions

And this is why I know it isn't any of those issues:

1. Outlook client and OWA online portal confirm primary SMTP to be `Michael.Wiley@<SOME DOMAIN>`
2. Code is authenticating at `https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`, if the password or username is changed, **only then** do I get a `401 Unauthorized`
3. I'm not impersonating in this code

---

### EDIT: PLEASE READ

After I finished posting this question I went back to the application and refreshed the page. The application was working again and displaying correctly:

[image: Correct Display]

**What could cause this issue and how do I avoid it in the future?**

Answer (score 1):

For the endpoint url:

```
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

You should use [Autodiscover](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900169(v=exchg.150).aspx) , this is the standard way from MSDN. Autodiscover is typically used to find the EWS endpoint URL, but Autodiscover can also provide information to configure clients that use other protocols.

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user1@contoso.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

It needs a callback function, please refer this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx).

As you said, sometimes you application worked, you can enable the [EWS trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) to trace the web request, you should be able to find out why.